# Math: Five numbers with unique sums

Tags: math, numbers, sum, unique

So I need a way to figure out how to get 5 numbers, and when you add any 2 of them, it will result in a sum that you can only get by adding those specific two numbers.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about, but with 3 numbers:

1
3
5

1 + 3 = 4
1 + 5 = 6
3 + 5 = 8

Adding any two of those numbers will end up with a unique sum that cannot be found by adding any other pair of the numbers. I need to do this, but with 5 different numbers. And if you have a method of figuring out how to do this with any amount of numbers, sharing that would be appreciated as well.
Thank you

Comment: What about `{1, 2, 4, 8, 16}`? It even has the property that every subset sums to a unique number (look at the binary representation).

Comment: I believe this is called a <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidon_sequence">Sidon Set</a>.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`1, 10, 100, 10000, 100000` gives you five numbers like you desire.

In general, `1, 10, 100, 1000, ..., 10^k` where `k` is the number of numbers that you need.

And even more general, you can say `b^0, b^1, ..., b^k`, where `b >= 2`. Note that you have the special property that not only are all the pairwise sums unique, but all the subset sums are unique (just look at representations in base `b`).

Comment: Looks like we thought about the same solution :)

Comment: Even more, by adding at most one of each of numbers of the form b^0, b^1, b^2, ..., b^k, you can get *any* number between 1 and b^(k+1)-1.  This is exactly what makes them useful as a base.  Any set of numbers where the n-th number is larger than the previous two would also satisfy op's problem *(So, for example, `f(n) = Fib(n) + n` would work)*.  But I wonder if there are any solutions that *aren't* like that?

Comment: Actually it only needs to be >=, so the Fibonacci sequence directly would work.  I've figured out how to prove that this is the "thinnest" such sequence also.

Answer (score 4):

The set `{1, 2, 5, 11, 21}` also works.

You can start with a set of two or three elements that fit that property (any addition operation on two elements from the set `{1,2,5}` gives you an unique sum) and only include the next number being considered if additions of current elements and this new element also give you unique sums.

An example run-through:

Suppose our starting set `S` is `S={1,2,5}`. Let `U` be the set of all sums between two elements in `S`.
Elements in `S` give us unique sums `1+2=3`, `1+5=6`, `2+5=7`,  so `U={3,6,7}`.

Consider adding `11` to this set. We need to check that `1+11`, `2+11`, and `5+11` all give us sums that are not seen in `U` and are all unique among themselves.

`1+11=12`, `2+11=13`, `5+11=17`.

Since `12`, `13`, and `17` are all unique sums among themselves, and are not found in `U`, we can update `S` and `U` to be:
`S1 = {1,2,5,11}`
`U1 = {3,6,7,12,13,17}`.

You can do the same procedure for `21`, and you should (hopefully) get:
`S2 = {1,2,5,11,21}`
`U2 = {3,6,7,12,13,17,22,23,26,32}`.

If all you need is a quick set though, the solution that Jason posted is a lot faster to produce.

Comment: An even closer set of numbers would be {1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21 etc.} See my comment to @Jason's answer above.

Answer (score 2):

```
1
2
4
8
16

1
3
9
27
81
```

suggests x ^ n where n is a member of a subset of Natural numbers